# how to find by multiple optional criteria and a OneToMany relationship using Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I tried to solve this by using QueryDsl but it does not work I asked in This question [Spring data and QueryDsl, how to find by multiple criteria in one row and a OneToMany relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37425016/spring-data-and-querydsl-how-to-find-by-multiple-criteria-in-one-row-and-a-onet)

The Problem is I have two tables a Person and its clothes.

```
PersonID |PersonFirstname|PersonLastname
========================================
1        |Jack           |      Jackson  
2        |Kelly          |      Kellson
```

Then the Person Table could be (OneToMany by PersonId)

```
ID | PersonID | Jacket | Color | Size
========================================
1  |1         |Nike    | black | XL  
2  |1         |ADIDAS  | white | XL
3  |1         |Prada   | green | L  
4  |1         |ADIDAS  | blue  | XL

5  |2         |Reebock | yellow| S 
6  |2         |Majestic| brown | XS
7  |2         |Prada   | green | M
```

> From my other question:
>   If I now write a query like this
>
> ```
> findPersonWho.and(person.personClothes.any().jacket.eq("Nike")
>                 .and(person.personClothes.any().color.eq("black"))
>                 .and(person.personClothes.any().size.eq("L")));
> ```
>
> It will return me the Person with the ID 1, because he has a jacket from
>   nike and a color black and a size L.
>
> But I only want Patient 1 if he has a Jacket from nike with the color
>   black and the size L.

Now I tried to do this on an other way, I wrote a new method to search only in the clothes Table like this

```
if (jacket != null) {
        findPerson.and(p.jacket.eq("Nike").and(p.ecolor.eq("black").and(p.size.eq(L))));
}
```

And this works, but if I now want to use the BooleanBuilder to find by multiple criteria in this Table like some more Person with a Jacket from Reebock in the color yellow and the size s like this:

```
if (jacket1 != null) {
        findPerson.and(p.jacket.eq("Nike").and(p.ecolor.eq("black").and(p.size.eq(L))));
}
if (jacket2 != null {
        findPerson.and(p.jacket.eq("Reebock").and(p.ecolor.eq("yellow").and(p.size.eq(S))));
```

This will return me 0 but in fact, there are two matches. But I think he is now searching by the ID and not by the PationID. So there are no ID 1 with booth matches..

Is there any way to do this search? maybe with an other approach?

Answer (score 0):

Try Following and replace Search with your whatever you want to search

```
Criteria person = sf.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Person.class).createAlias("personId", "personId");

person.add(Restrictions.disjunction().add(Restrictions.ilike("PersonFirstname",Search,MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
.add(Restrictions.ilike("personId.Jacket",Search,MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
.add(Restrictions.ilike("personId.Color",Search,MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
.add(Restrictions.ilike("personId.Size",Search,MatchMode.ANYWHERE)));
```

Comment: it is your Session